# Não sei porque que meu programa não funciona!! EM C

Tags: c

No exercício eu preciso criar uma struct e envia-la para a função que verifica se o numero eh par, se sim ele envia para outra função que devolve o numero /2.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dados{
int numero;
char nome[5];
};

void manipula_um_par (int *a){
    *a = *a/2;
}

int *manipula_pares (struct dados x[10], int w){
    int z;
    for(z=0;z<w;z++){
        if (x[z].numero %2==0){
            manipula_um_par(&x[z].numero);
        }
    }
    return x[10].numero;
}

int main(){
    struct dados v[10];
    int a[10];
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
        printf("\nDigite o nome do %d aluno: ",x+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(v[x].nome, 20, stdin);
        printf("\nDigite o %d numero: ",x+1);
        scanf("%d",&v[x].numero);
        }
    *a = manipula_pares(&v.numero,10);
    for(x=0;x<10;x++){
    printf("--- %d ",a[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x[10]` não existe. `x` é um array de dez elementos: `x[0]`, `x[1]`, ...`x[9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur,

Corrigi o erro que tinha e fiz algumas sugestões de melhoria.

Comentei as melhorias no código para ter uma referência melhor sobre o que estou falando.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    // É uma boa prática de programação definir os números que são usados em vários lugares, com um define, vocÊ pode alterar a quantia sem risco de esquecer algum lugar
    #define NUM_ALUNOS 10

    struct dados{
      int numero;
      char nome[5]; // Não alterei, mas 5 é pouco para um nome, sugeriria utilizar um vetor maior
    };

    // É uma boa prática de programação definir os protótipos das funções no início do programa (aconselho pesquisar sobre)
    void manipula_um_par (int *a);
    void manipula_pares (struct dados *x, int w);

    int main()
    {
        struct dados v[NUM_ALUNOS];
        // int a[10]; Neste caso, não será necessário utilizar este vetor
        int x;

        for(x = 0; x < NUM_ALUNOS; x++)
        {        
            printf("\nDigite o nome do %d aluno: ",x+1);
            // fflush(stdin);
            // fgets(v[x].nome, 20, stdin);
            scanf("%s", v[x].nome); // Acredito que o scanf servirá bem neste caso 

            printf("\nDigite o %d numero: ",x+1);
            scanf("%d",&v[x].numero);
        }

        // *a é a mesma coisa que a[0], então neste caso, você não estará mudando todo o vetor de inteiros, você só estará mudando o primeiro vetor
        // Já que você já passa o struct v, não tem necessidade de utilizar o vetor a, pois você já esta passando os dados dentro do vetor e só precisa imprimir
        // Se você quisesse utilizar o "a", você teria que passado como parâmetro manipula_pares(&v.numero, 10, a) e trocaria o protótipo da função para void manipula_pares (struct dados *x, int w, int *a); e modificaria dentro da função o vetor a
        // Foi trocado o retorno da sua função, pois não precisaremos mais do retorno, já que alteramos tudo dentro da própria função
        // Como o *a é a mesma coisa que o a[0], então isso é um inteiro e sua função estava retornando um porteiro de inteiro e colocando um inteiro
        // *a = manipula_pares(&v.numero,10);
        manipula_pares(v, NUM_ALUNOS);

        for(x=0;x<NUM_ALUNOS;x++) 
        {
          // Como foi falado, troquei para ao invés de imprimir o vetor a, imprimir direto a struct
          printf("--- %d ", v[x].numero);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void manipula_um_par (int *a)
    {
        *a = *a/2;
    }

    void manipula_pares(struct dados *x, int w)
    {
        int z;
        for(z=0;z<w;z++)
        {
            if (x[z].numero % 2 == 0){
                manipula_um_par(&x[z].numero);
            }
        }
    }
```

Um último comentário, é uma boa prática colocar nomes mais representativos em suas variáveis/funções, assim fica mais fácil de outras pessoas ler e entender o fluxo do seu código e para o que serve cada pedaço de código.